# Form of Devi attached to Ardhanarishwera form of Shiva

Tags: shiva, goddess, devi, durga, nava-durga

As per [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Cn-r5gnGtF0), Devi Siddhidatri, 9th form of Goddess Durga is attached to Ardhanarishwera form of Shiva. Is it correct? If not, then which form of devi Durga is she? Looking for scriptural reference.